# Ionic 4 page animation page Div part move up words and down by click up arrow / down Arraow

Tags: user-interface, ionic-framework, html5-canvas, ionic4

Any one can help me in Ionic 4 am using the ionic page, In that page i have Div area (Please refer attachment image)

By clicking that Up arrow that div has to move Up Top of the page below up to below header part. By Cliking Down Arrow then that div back previous same position. How can be done ?

Any one can guide me how to solve this . Thank you

[image]

Comment: change position on click event. use `[ngStyle]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow is designed to solve your code/bugs related problems. Not to actually write the code for the application.

Use [Ionic Animations](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations).